# ¿Qué entiende la RAE como "especie" en las definiciones de "padre" y "madre"?

Tags: definiciones, vocabulario-técnico, dle, rae

Aviso que esta pregunta es de ponerme muy [puntilloso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UgE1IxP) con la RAE.

---

Leo en las definiciones de *[padre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RQfIvcj)* y *madre* lo siguiente:

> Varón o animal macho que ha engendrado a otro ser de su misma especie.
>   Mujer o animal hembra que ha parido a otro ser de su misma especie.

Ahora bien, ¿qué entiende la RAE como *[especie](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GWfgJDk)* en este caso? Si nos ponemos botánicos, la definición sería:

> *Bot. y Zool.* Cada uno de los grupos en que se dividen los géneros y que se componen de individuos que, además de los caracteres genéricos, tienen en común otros caracteres por los cuales se asemejan entre sí y se distinguen de los de las demás especies. La especie se subdivide a veces en variedades o razas.

Y entonces se me viene a la cabeza el [mulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mula_(animal)), que es un híbrido entre un burro y una yegua. Según la Wikipedia, el [burro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equus_africanus_asinus) pertenece a la especie *Equus africanus*, y el [caballo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equus_ferus_caballus) a la *Equus ferus*. El mulo pertenecería a la especie *Equus africanus♂ x Equus ferus♀*, que no tengo claro si es una especie nueva o el conjunto de ambas especies. Otros ejemplos serían el [ligre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligre) (*Panthera leo♂ x Panthera tigris♀*) y el [tigón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tig%C3%B3n) (Panthera tigris♂ x Panthera leo♀). Nótese que la forma de referenciar a la especie es diferente en ambos casos.

Lo que sí comparten burros y caballos es el género (*Equus*), y lo mismo para el ligre y el tigón (*Panthera*). Luego pregunto: ¿qué entiende como *especie* la RAE en sus definiciones para *padre* y *madre*? ¿Es la especie zoológica o es otra clase de especie? ¿Sería más adecuado usar "género zoológico" en vez de "especie"? Offtopic preguntado en el sitio de biología: [¿las especies cruzadas se consideran como la fusión de las dos especies padres, o se consideran especies aparte?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85084/52223) Y más offtopic porque esto es más opinión que otra cosa: ¿no habría sido mejor decir simplemente "que ha engendrado/parido descendencia", como el diccionario de Oxford?

---

Curiosidad: el cruce de un caballo con una burra es un [burdégano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burd%C3%A9gano).

Comment: Entiendo que la definición técnica de "especie" no es en absoluto sencilla; la definición del DLE basta para la inmensa mayoría de los casos y no yerra mucho en los otros, aunque como decís, mejor hubiera sido ni mencionar eso de "de la misma especie".

Comment: *offtopic* En la definición de especie que has citado del DLE hay un error: «... y se distinguen **de los** de las demás especies.»

Comment: No es ningún error. El sujeto de la frase subordinada es "individuos". La parte implícita es "se distinguen de los [individuos] de las demás especies".

Comment: Los Mulos, o Mulas como se les conoce acá en Colombia, no son una especie, ya que no se pueden reproducir.. son solo un híbrido

Comment: Lo que define a una especie con reproducción sexual  es precisamente que no se hibrida con otros seres.   Que a veces existan híbridos solo indica que, donde vemos dos especies, solo hay una,  con una  divergencia evolutiva más incipiente   (híbridos fértiles),  avanzada (híbridos con claras desventajas o  está terminando  (híbridos infértiles).  Que a veces no estén claros los límites de la especie no significa que padre y madres puedan engendrar seres de otras especies. Porque si lo hacen, entonces no engendran  hijos, sino parásitos.

Answer (score 1):

La RAE, a pesar de que incluye una definición de carácter más o menos técnico para *especie*, no pretende ser rigurosamente científica. Ofrece, en cambio, varias definiciones referidas a *usos habituales* de las palabras, algunas de las cuales serán más "científicas" que otras.

Si alguna definición nos parece ambigua, contradictoria, obsoleta o poco rigurosa es porque se usa o se ha usado con significados que desde nuestra *actual* perspectiva o conocimiento no son válidos. Y los significados habituales de las palabras cambian mucho más lentamente que los avances de las disciplinas que estudian los referentes de esas palabras. Pero ahí quedan ellas disponibles para seguir usándolas:  decimos *ponerse sol* y la RAE define *poner* como "ocultarse en el horizonte", aunque hace tiempo que sabemos que al sol en realidad nadie lo pone.

La definición 1 de *padre* ("Varón o animal macho que ha engendrado a otro ser de su misma especie")  sirve muy bien para el "caballo" que engendró otro caballo.

Para el "caballo" que engendró una mula nos sirve en cambio la 5, que es más general (y podríamos decir que más anticuada):

> Animal macho que ha engendrado una o más crías.

Podemos pedirle al DRAE que actualice sus definiciones de *padre* y de *especie*, pero no podemos pedirle que se apure en ello ni que sea tan meticulosamente preciso, dado que lo que le interesa son los usos habituales.

Si estás escribiendo un artículo técnico sobre genética, reproducción o taxonimía, entonces **debes incluir tus propias definiciones**, que deben ser válidas en tu propio texto. Ahí no te sirve la RAE, a menos que haya sido suficientemente aclarado.